# Can i give Commands from Excel Sheet for Arithmetic Operators in Selenium using Data driven Approach?

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Data driven Approach for Selenium Framework where giving all the commands from Excel sheet using Apache poi Api. But when I am writing the Script for Comparing two values and when i am calling this function from Excel sheet, Normally running the program.But i want to enter the values from Excel sheet only whenever it will show it is greater than or less than value.

Can you guys help me with this so that whenever if it will show value is greater then it should automatically take lesser values from excel sheet and Vice Versa.

I am attaching my Script here for more understanding.

```
public void Alarm(int testData,String objectName ) throws Exception{
        int c=0;
        int count=testData;
        while(c < count)
        {
        System.out.println("Entering into loop");
        String a="90";
        String b=driver.findElement(By.xpath
                (prop.getProperty(
                        objectName))).getText();
        String i=a;
        String j=b;

        String numberOnlyA= a.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        String numberOnlyB= b.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        System.out.println(numberOnlyA);
        System.out.println(numberOnlyB);

        if(Integer.parseInt(numberOnlyA.trim())> Integer.parseInt(numberOnlyB.trim()))
        {
            System.out.println("Alarm will get generated Insert the values which will be less than Cut in values");
            //getPValues(testData, objectName);



        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Alarm will not get generated insert the offset values which will be greater from cut out values");
            //input(String.valueOf(testData), objectName);


        }
        c=c+1;


        System.out.println(c);
        }

        if(c==count)
        {
            System.out.println("Lockout hapened clear the ockout");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("dont clear the lockout");
        }


}
```